# CentOS6 Iptables deletes rule after 24 hour

Tags: iptables, centos6, service

Since I updated my CentOS server with yum update and now some of my iptable rules get deleted after a while. When I notice the server closed down my port I can simply fix this by:

`service iptables restart`

A restart of my server closes the port aswell.

So every time I do a iptables restart it opens the port again.
Yes, I've tried using the service iptables save, this won't help me.

Can anyone explain me why this problem occurs?

Comment: More details are required from you. Which ports are being blocked ? Show us the output of iptables -L -vn before the problem occurs and when the problem occurs.

Comment: I've just opened the file iptables.save and found out my rules are double written inside the file? Can this be an issue?

Comment: Have you cehcked logs? It seems to be quite obvioous that the settings aer not persisting - and likely something does a restart / reload of the IpTabels rules once per day. Not a Linux guy myself I would assume there is a log somewhere with an error for the save.

Comment: Yeah i thought exactly the same @TomTom! However I'm just like you not a Linux genius.

Comment: This might seem a bit far-fetched, but its probably worth checking your cron job lists.

Comment: Are you filling your firewall rules only by iptables command, or do you use some kind of iptables tool? And so nothing appears in messages/secure/cron log as TomTom suggested? You didn't answer that one ;-)

Comment: My bad guys, I'll add my rules by the following commands: iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --sport 9987 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Maybe there is an application causing the issue?  Maybe there is an application that automatically sets iptables rules that is working inappropriately.

Comment: @DavidEisen I'm currently using CentOS (6) builded with DirectAdmin's custombuild. Never had this problem before till I updated the the complete server with "yum update".

Comment: When the iptables doesn't work are the rules shown? Is the service iptables down? Last but not least: cornjob's, dmesg and syslog? Provide moar info

Comment: @ochach, i would love to give some information but I'm not an expert in Linux. So maybe you could tell me what info you exactly need. The system doesn't have any cronjobs, except for DirectAdmin. DirectAdmin doesn't modify iptables if i'm right?

Answer (score 2):

You're almost certainly editing the rules while it's running and not saving them correctly. The rules file you want is `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. Edit that, then `service iptables restart` to get the behavior you want. This will persist across reboots.

Comment: Will give this a try tonight :)! Seems like the fix I hope.

Comment: Oh, just found out my rules are already in that file?

Answer (score 0):

Issue this command to activate iptables on every runlevel:

> chkconfig iptables on

and after that, you can save your rules with `iptables-save` (as you do normally) and it will keep it after restart the service as you want.

> service iptables restart

Comment: I'm not really sure if this will fix it. Whenever I use the "service iptables restart" it fixes my problem when my ports are closed. I'll give it a try and let you know tomorrow if my ports are still open.

Comment: `chkconfig --list | grep iptables` will tell you if it is on by default.